# How to get a session variable using PHP while login in another web application?

Tags: php, session

I am new in PHP. I want to display session variables like session id, user name, team name etc from a web application. My scenario is I am login in an independent web application. I use php code to display my session variables while login in that web application.

My code is here

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<?php
print_r($_SESSION);
?>
```

But i failed to display session data. My code output is a blank array.

can anyone help me how i can get session data?

Comment: Are you storing them to Session? If yes, where?

Comment: @b0s3 i am newly born in php. I can not understand storing of data. can you please explain it. i am thankfull to you

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php

Comment: Google is really helpful I think.

Answer (score 1):

You have not set values to session anywhere.

Try

```
<?php
session_start();

$_SESSION['username'] = 'logged_username';
$_SESSION['id'] = '007';

print_r($_SESSION);
?>
```

Comment: *You have not set values to session anywhere.* - How do you know it is not set? There might be some errors or OP might have tried nothing.

Comment: Hassan i dont know column name in db than how i can use that? lets suppose i am login in facebook. then here i want to display session data. How it is possible?

Comment: @sunny There are a lot of thing you need learn first before doing whatever you want to do. Go through the basics first.

Comment: @b0s3 can you please refer me a link?

Comment: @b0s3 in his code he does set values to session anywhere. I agree with you, he need to learn basics first.

Comment: @sunny You can't get session data from another web application unless the web applications are on the same server, or store session data in the same database/datastore.

Answer (score 0):

**Start a PHP Session**

```
<?php
// Start the session
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
// Set session variables
$_SESSION["favcolor"] = "green";
$_SESSION["favanimal"] = "cat";
echo "Session variables are set.";
?>

</body>
</html>
```

then use

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
print_r($_SESSION);
?>

</body>
</html>
```

[W3School Example](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp)

Comment: Abdulla i dont know column name in db than how i can use that? lets suppose i am login in facebook. then here i want to display session data. How it is possible?

Comment: ya you need to assig the vales to session verioubles

Answer (score 0):

To Use session data you first need to store some data in session

```
<?php
session_start(); // start your session its better you start your session in configuration file 

// create some global variables using session
$_SESSION['user_name'] = "Your Name";
$_SESSION['team_name'] = "Your Team Name";
?>
```

To use session

```
echo $_SESSION['user_name']
// output - Your Name
```

> check session ref - [Session in php](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php)

Comment: Meenesh i dont know column name in db than how i can use that? lets suppose i am login in facebook. then here i want to display session data. How it is possible?

Comment: using session can be a bit tricky so its better you should have proper information of what you want to be in session because session variable are globally alive.

Answer (score 0):

first you have to start session at very first of your php application using `session_start()` function.
and then set session variable with key like this

```
$_SESSION['user'] = $user
```

access these variable same way.

```
print_r($_SESSION['user'])
```

Dont forget to start session while access on other file.

Comment: MD i dont know column name in db than how i can use that? lets suppose i am login in facebook. then here i want to display session data. How it is possible?

Comment: session is responsible for storing data just like variable to be globaly used. No matter how you get data from database, from hard coded, or from apis.

Comment: if you want to use fb login, then see proper documentation for that, get user details from fb login api and save to session variable if you want to keep records you have to store it in db also